# Natural transformation for functors $\Bbb Z \to G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

> Let $G$ be a group. For each $g \in G$, there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi: \Bbb Z \to G$ satisfying $\varphi(1) = g$. Thus, elements of $G$ are essentially the same thing as homomorphisms $\Bbb Z \to G$. When groups are regarded as one-object categories, homomorphisms $\Bbb Z \to G$ are in turn the same as functors $\Bbb Z \to G$. Natural isomorphism defines an equivalence relation on the set of functors $\Bbb Z \to G$, and, therefore, an equivalence relation on $G$ itself. What is this equivalence relation, in purely group-theoretic terms?

So I'm bit lost with the symbols here... If $F,H : \Bbb Z \to G$ are functors, then a natural transformation $\eta$ is a collection $(\eta_A:F(A) \to H(A))_{A \in \Bbb Z}$ that for a morphism $f : A \to A'$ satisfy $$\eta_{A'}\circ F(f)=H(f)\circ \eta_A.$$

However since $\Bbb Z$ is treated as a category it has only one object say $\bullet_\Bbb Z$ and similarly $G$ has only one object say $\bullet_G$. A morphism $f :\bullet_\Bbb Z \to \bullet_\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Z$ is essentially just an integer $n$ and the natural transformation $\eta$ contains only one map $\eta_{\bullet_\Bbb Z}:F(\bullet_\Bbb Z )\to H(\bullet_\Bbb Z)$. But as $G$ contains also only one object $F(\bullet_\Bbb Z ) = H(\bullet_\Bbb Z ) = \bullet_G$ which should mean that $\eta_{\bullet_\Bbb Z}$ is a group element say $g$.

So is this saying that $$gn = ng$$ which would give $gng^{-1}=n$ and the equivalence relation would be conjugacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct, but what you write does not make sense: $gng^{-1}$ multiplies an element of $G$ with an integer, which we can't do. Let's be more careful.

Let me use $\bullet$ for the unique object of the category $\mathbb{Z}$, and $\star$ for the unique object of the category $G$.

A functor $\mathbb{Z}\to G$, viewed as categories, corresponds to picking an element $g\in G$ and sending the morphism $n\colon\bullet\to\bullet$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, to the morphism $g^n\colon\star\to\star$. Let us denote this functor by $F_g$.

A natural transformation $\eta$ between two functors $\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G}\colon\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{D}$ means a collection of maps $\eta_A\colon \mathscr{F}(A)\to \mathscr{G}(A)$, indexed by the *objects* of $\mathsf{C}$, such that for every $f\in\mathsf{C}(A,A')$ we have $\eta_{A'}\circ \mathscr{F}(f) = \mathscr{G}(f)\circ \eta_A$. Here, because the categories $\mathbb{Z}$ and $G$ have only one object, natural transformations are just a single function $\star\to\star$.

So, for functors $F_g,F_h\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$, a natural transformation $\Phi\colon F_g\to F_h$ is then a single morphism $\phi\colon \star\to\star$ (i.e., an element of $G$, say $x$) such that for each function $\bullet\to\bullet$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ (that is, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$),
$$\phi\circ F_g(n) = F_h(n)\circ\phi.$$
So we are saying that
$$xg^n = h^nx$$
must hold for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$; that is, $xg^nx^{-1}=h^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ must hold in $G$. This is equivalent to $xgx^{-1}=h$ holding in $G$. Thus, there is a natural transformation between $F_g$ and $F_h$ if and only if $g$ and $h$ are conjugate in $G$, in which case the natural transformation is given by any conjugating element. Denote this natural transformation, given by the element $x$, by $\Phi_x$. So $\Phi_x\colon F_g\to F_h$ is a natural transformation when $xg=hx$, and vice versa: if $xg=hx$, then $\Phi_x\colon F_g\to F_h$ is a natural transformation.

Note that if $\Phi_x\colon F_g\to F_h$ is a natural transformation, then $\Phi_{x^{-1}}\colon F_h\to F_g$ will be a natural transformation and $\Phi_{x^{-1}}\Phi_{x}=\Phi_e$ is the identity natural transformation of $F_g$ to itself; and $\Phi_x\Phi_{x^{-1}}=\Phi_e$ is the identity natural transformation from $F_h$ to itself. So $F_g$ and $F_h$ are naturally equivalent if and only if $g$ and $h$ are conjugate in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I got a bit lost with the formalities. @arturo-magidin